# Retrieving values of a specific field in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Consider a class:

```
class Employee{
 Integer empId,
  //many other fields
}
```

I need a DAO method as shown below

```
 List<Integer> getAllEmployeeIds(){
 //??
 }
I dont want List<Employee> and  (NEW EDIT) Set<Intger>
```

How can i do that in hibernate?Am using hbm files for mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this. Also, I recommend use [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) to make it type-safe.

```
List<Integer> getAllEmployeeIds(){
    return (List<Integer>)createQuery("select e.empId from Employee e").list();
}
```

Comment: What if i want to create  a Set.Eg Set<Integer>?

Comment: You can call addAll() on your set.

Answer (score 1):

use an hql query and do something like

```
String hql = "select E.empId from Employee E";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<Integer> ids = query.list();
```

follow the documentation from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/).

Comment: Can i map it to a set (Set<Interger>)?

Comment: you can take the List and simply create a set.